# Netplan Configuration

Tags: networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, netplan, rasberrypi

When I apply the configuration below, everything works fine (IE.: I am able to reach my server over eth0 and wlan0).  But, after applying the netplan configuration, I received the following output:

**** (generate:22200): WARNING **: 17:21:13.188: Problem encountered while validating default route consistency.Please set up multiple routing tables and use `routing-policy` instead.
Error: Conflicting default route declarations for IPv4 (table: main, metric: default), first declared in wlan0 but also in eth0"**

My netplan configuration looks like this:

```
network:
version: 2
ethernets:
    eth0:
        addresses: [192.168.50.212/24]
        gateway4: 192.168.50.1
        optional: true
        dhcp4: false
        nameservers:
                addresses: [1.1.1.1,1.0.0.1]
# add wifi setup information here ...
wifis:
    wlan0:
        addresses: [192.168.50.212/24]
        optional: true
        gateway4: 192.168.50.1
        access-points:
            "my_ssid":
                password: "password_here"
        dhcp4: false
        nameservers:
                addresses: [1.1.1.1,1.0.0.1]
```

~
I have looked for days but cannot find a solution to fix the issue.  Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: This question has been asked and answered at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1008571/how-can-i-configure-default-route-metric-with-dhcp-and-netplan#1014760

Comment: I'm afraid that this didn't help me but thank you for your reply.  I do note that by by deleting "gateway4" from wlan0, I no longer get the error message.  But in doing so, I am blocked from reaching my server from outside of my network (if my raspberry pi is disconnected from eth0) something I am attempting to avoid.

Comment: Did you add lines similar to the "routes" lines under enp0s8, on the answer I linked to which is analogous to your wlan interface?  Those lines create a backup gateway out the second device (ie to: 0.0.0.0/0 = default route, via =192.168.50.1 in your case - the router IP address, metric: 50 means that it is a backup default gateway which will only be used if the main one stops working)

Comment: Hi, yes, after digging in a little deeper, I seem to have resolved the problem thanks to your guidance.  That being said, I'm using a routing metric of 100 for eth0 and for wlan0, I have it set to 200.  Is this optimal?  Many thanks as I still get the hang of using netplan :)

Comment: The metric numbers don't really matter, provided one is bigger then the other.  (ie a metric of 1 and 2 would have the same effect here as 100 and 200 - its just a way for the OS to order priority or routes.

Comment: Thanks, this was a huge help :)

Comment: One thing that I have observed with this configuration is that it takes about 5 minutes after reboot before the server comes back up.  Is this to be expected?  I have never experienced this prior to configuring routes tables in netplan.

Comment: By "come back up" I mean that I cannot ssh the machine or access 2 public facing websites I run.

Comment: I don't know.   I've only used Netplan a few times.  Adding routes should not cause this problem in theory.  I've just seen  that you have both the ethernet and and wlan port with the same IP. This is really a no-no.  The appropriate solution (and not sure how you would do it in Netplan, but its likely possible) would be to channel bond your ethernet and wlan ports together, and then set up the interface on the "bond" interface, and use bonding to do the balancing - maybe pusing active-backup mode.

Comment: Also, I've not tried it, but it looks like netplan has an option "address ip_failover) which you can use on your backup interface - see https://www.scaleway.com/en/docs/dedibox-network/ip-failover/how-to/configure-debian-ubuntu/

Comment: Thanks, will check it out.